# Propagating specific touch event to view underneath

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I want to implement a feature similar to this:

View A and View B are all child views of the same parent UIView. View A and View B are sibling views. View A is the same frame size as the parent view. View B is only half of the size and it's above View A. I want to capture swipe events/gestures on View B, but still propagate other events/gestures (e.g. Tap) from View B to View A. So user can still interact with View A (e.g. tap on the button on View A) while View B is only capturing swipe gestures.

I have tried implementing following methods on View B

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

but seems like it's all or nothing approach. as I cannot detect in these methods if the event is a tap or a swipe. And I didn't find any API which can programatically trigger a tap on a UIView (not calling touch related methods).

Comment: Detecting different types of gestures is very difficult. Why do not you use gesture recognizers?

Comment: @macmoonshine I tried gesture recognisers, but didn't seem work. View B and View A are sibling views. I don't know how I can pass gesture events from View B to View A as View B is on top of View A.

Comment: You can add the recognizer to a common superview.

Answer (score 3):

You should move your rear sibling view to be a subview of the front view as this effective looks the same but makes the UIResponder chain behave correctly.  UIGestureRecognizer can then do the rest of the work for you.  Specifically it has a property, [CancelsTocuhesInViews](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624218-cancelstouchesinview) that you can turn off so it doesn't eat touch events and it has a delegate with methods that can allow you to specify the conditions under which a UIGestureRegonizer should fire.  Implement the [UIGestureRecognizerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate) methods that you want to make your logic work.  For instance if you want the overlay view to handle a tap only if a bunch of other gestureRecognizers don't handle the tap first then you implement [gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRequireFailureOf:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624229-gesturerecognizer) and have it return true for every other gesture recognizer you want to go first; your gesture recognizer will then only fire when all of these other gesture recognizers have failed to handle the tap.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, what you want to do is usually done using UIGestureRecognizer objects and its subclasses. You can make one gesture recognizer (i.e. a swipe (or was it pan?) gesture recognizer) depend on another one (one for taps).

You can tell one gesture recognizer to only trigger when another has failed to detect its gesture. I haven't had to do that yet, so can't give you more detail, but I'd look into those classes and see if there's a way to chain them so it handles a swipe, and just *does not* handle taps. If you don't handle a tap, it should automatically go to any subview that will handle it, I think.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The issue here is View A and View B are sibling views which are subviews of the same parent view. I tried the UIGestureRecognizer  approach. I can handle swipe gesture on View B. but  how can I pass the tap gesture happened on View B to View A as View B is always on top of View A which blocks all user interactions.

Comment: Can you change the order of your views? Also, not sure if that breaks the cleanness of your hierarchy, but could you install the gesture recognizer on the parent view, and then do the reverse? If you detect the pan gesture, pass the pan to the view, otherwise tell the view to return NO from its hitTest(_:withEvent:) method?